# Variable not changing from user input in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, switch-statement, global-variables

I'm trying to create multiple calculators in the C++ console for *Geometry Theorems* and other formulas in *Algebra,* and for some weird reason on the start of the program, when selecting an option the variable `scene` does not want to change(shown before the array of `calculators[]`, and instead of going to the *Pythagorean Theorem*(`scene 1`), the console says, *"Press any key to continue. . ."* and closes.

I've tried both the `switch()` and`if()` statements to navigate scene management, but what am I doing incorrectly? (I'm still a C++ learner by the way, but I have other programming language experience).

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int scene(0);
char calculators[3][25] = 
{
    "",
    "Pythagorean Theorem",
    "Homer's Formula"
};
void selection() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number to select a calculator." << std::endl; // Opening
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i += 1) {
        std::cout << "Option " << i << ": " << calculators[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void pTheorem() 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::cout << "Enter side a: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter side b: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "Side length of c is " << sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)) << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    switch(scene) 
    {
        case 0:
            selection();
            std::cin >> scene;
            std::cout << "You've selected the " << calculators[scene] << " Calculator" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            pTheorem();
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add your code to question.

Comment: use `std::string` instead of char array and use `std::vector<>` to store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `scene` has been declared and initialized `0` at the beginning(globally) itself. This will give you always the same switch `case = 0`. Changing `scene` inside the `switch` cases will not work. Instead, you need to input the `scene` before the `switch`.

```
int main()
{
    selection();
    int scene = 0;
    std::cin >> scene;
    switch(scene)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

Secondly, use `std::string` instead of char array and use `std::vector<>`/`std::array` to store them. For example:

```
std::array<std::string,2> calculators =
{
    "Pythagorean Theorem",
    "Homer's Formula"
};
```

and `for` loop can be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        std::cout << "Option " << i+1 << ": " << calculators[i] << std::endl;
```